# Загрузка страницы html целиком из stream

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, html

**Доброго времени суток, Уважаемые Хэшкодовцы!**

Есть такая задачка: Загрузить страницу html из памяти в webbrowser (IHTMLDocument2).
Страница расположена в базе данных (отдельно html, отдельно картинки, отдельно скрипты, отдельно css). Связь между файлами является непосредственно ссылки на файлы в html. Собственно говоря, достать все данные из базы - проблем не составляет.

Страницу HTML достаточно легко загрузить в webbrowser через DocumentStream, однако все ресурсы страницы не подгружаются (и это понятно), но как их подсунуть? Перегуглил и переяндексил все, на что хватило ума, но так и не нашел ответа на свою проблему.

Если страницу грузить с жесткого диска или с http://, то все ресурсы корректно загружаются и список картинок, например, доступен в HTMLDocument.Images. Данное свойство доступно только на чтение, и не получается туда подсунуть требуемые ресурсы картинок.

Есть ли варианты решения моей проблемы?

**Заранее благодарю за наводки по решению моей проблемы.**

Comment: Ох. Ну и задача у Вас.

Есть несколько подходов.

1) Самый простой — модифицировать документ. Для этого Вам придётся его самостоятельно распарсить (HtmlAgilityPack?) после чтения из базы, найти все ссылки на внешние ресурсы и заменить их на ссылки на локальные ресурсы. Это можно, в принципе, сделать заранее, и положить в базу сразу модифицированный html. (Тогда можно в ту же базу положить и список необходимых ресурсов, если они тоже в базе и их надо доставать.)

Comment: 2. Вы можете загрузить документ как есть, перехватывать все обращения к внешним ресурсам и подставлять правильные ресурсы. Вот [код примера](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/157329/Http-Monitor-for-Webbrowser-Control) (он только подглядывает, но не меняет). Этот подход существенно сложнее, он требует низкоуровневого общения с COM.

Я бы рекомендовал первый путь, он как-то понятнее выглядит. Хотя реализовать второй путь, конечно, круто.

Comment: @vladd, не совсем понял, что такое локальный ресурс? Запихнуть все внешние файлы внутрь html? Он же дико распухнет, если картинки в него пихать. Они же в mime в него вливаются.
Второй путь шикарный, надо поглядеть. Я, если честно, о таком думал, но искал уже готовые события у документа и браузера...

Comment: @pincher1519: Ну, имеется в виду, положить его на диск. Хотя, конечно, чтение всего документа из памяти гораздо круче.

---
Вот [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/293017/276994) обсуждается ещё одна альтернатива:

1. Заменить `http://`-ссылки на `custom://`-ссылки.
2. Подключить свою реализацию протокола `custom://`, где вы уж можете делать всё, что угодно.

Comment: @VladD, а резве новый протокол в системе не нужно регистрировать?.. Не хотелось бы, чтобы программа требовала админские права для прописывания себя в системе... Этот вариант, пожалуй, оставлю на последок.

Comment: @VladD, может быть, Вы в курсе. Можно ли самостоятельно упаковать страницу в контейнер mht? Он, в принципе, кушается нормально, насколько могу судить... Можно было бы налету его формировать, и после закидывать его через поток в просмотрщик.

Comment: @pincher1519: ну про mht вот, например: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8268/Convert-any-URL-to-a-MHTML-archive-using-native-NE